# VirtualBox error - VM boots, but Windows 10 won't start

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run Windows 10 using VirtualBox on a Debian 9 machine. When trying to set up the VM, I couldn't choose the 64-bit version of Windows 10 in the menu, so I downloaded the 32-bit ISO instead. When trying to start the VM, I get the following error message:

[image: Error code]

What's the problem? Are there any good (and free) alternatives to VirtualBox that could do the job? I need to do this on a workplace machine on which I can do sudo, but have no root permissions (and this will most likely not change in the future).

UPDATE: I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/104017/878420) to check if VT-x is enabled and it seems to be *disabled* (the register returns `1` instead of `5`), but unfortunately I cannot do anything about this at the moment. *However*, after following Ramhound's links and the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36738186) to reduce the allocated RAM to below 3 GB, I got this prompt:

[image: Prompt]

I'm neither using OS/2 nor QNX - so when I click *Continue*, the VM actually seems to start and I even get the proper Windows startup screen:

[image: Windows screen]

It didn't progress from here until I finally switched off PAE/NX, and now I'm getting this **Windows 10 bluescreen**:

[image: Error code 0xc0000260]

Which is kind of strange, because the CPU (Intel Core i5-6500) supports PAE, so it should not be necessary (or even counter-productive) to disable PAE/NX, right?

Imho the VM is already up and running and it's just some VirtualBox setting(s) causing the hiccup. I feel like being *this* close to the solution... Here is the complete **[VirtualBox logfile](https://pastebin.com/EwgH0p87)**, maybe this contains some clues?

UPDATE: As Didier suggested, I also tried a ready-made Windows 10 VM as explained [here](https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/blog/Windows-Enterprise-Desktop/Download-Ready-to-Run-Windows-10-VMs). After downloading the VM from the [Microsoft Dev Center](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/) and fixing a minor [error/incompatibility](https://schnouki.net/post/2020/how-to-run-a-win10-dev-vm-on-virtualbox-5/) (in 2020, absolutely *nothing* seems to work out of the box anymore), I tried to start the VM. Result:

[image: Startup screen]
[image: Bluescreen]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106196/discussion-on-question-by-david-virtualbox-error-vm-boots-but-windows-10-won).

Comment: @Didier: Ok, many thanks!! Will try the ready-made VMs, maybe I can even activate them using my license key...

Comment: A tremendous alternative to Virtual Box is VMware Workstation. It will install and run both 32-bit  operating systems and 64-bit operating systems. VT-x needs to be enabled for 64-bit guests, but your 32-bit guest should install and run just fine.

Comment: Yes, I actually used to work with VMware Fusion on a Mac (great program!), but they only have commercial licenses afaik. By the way, I actually need to run the 64-bit version, the main only reason went with 32-bit is because VirtualBox didn't give me another choice

Comment: @david - You will still need VT-x enabled in order to run a 64-bit operating system within a VM, this will be the case, for any hypervisor that exists.  So contact your Administrator in order to enabled it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes for the error, see [this](https://appuals.com/fix-vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-all-cpu-modes-verr_vmx_msr_all_vmx_disabled/).

As per your description, check in your BIOS if VT-x is available and enabled.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304393/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabl).
Check if it is a RAM related issue (allocate less than 3Gb).
Check if turning PAE/NX on/off works (Virtual Box "Settings" > System Settings > Processor > Enable the PAE/NX option).
Check if also enabling VT-d at the BIOS level works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have permissions to access BIOS

Comment: @david - Then, your options are checking if conditions suggest the other possible points of actions are relevant, or trying them directly.
Please remember posting feedback!

Comment: Yes, I did (sorry, if that wasn't clear) and appended this to the question. It seems we're edging towards the solution, but it's not quite working yet

Comment: @david - Ok, it seems (perhaps) PAE/NX brought you closer to the solution. Good.

Comment: At first glance, yes! But paradoxically, the CPU does support PAE, so this option should be enabled...

Comment: @david - Well, the fact that the PC supports it doesn't mean it has to be enabled for a proper interaction with VBox, and for any VM.

Comment: Ok, that's very good to know! But could it be that by disabling PAE/NX in VirtualBox, the Windows 10 VM **thinks** that the CPU does not support PAE and therefore throws this 0xc0000260 error code? It says "This operating system uses the PAE feature [...]. You'll need to use a PC with a compatible processor to run the operating system."

Answer (score -1):

0x80004005 error may happen in the middle of Windows Update process which stops the update immediately. If this is the case, run the Windows Update troubleshooter to fix the issue. Here’s how.

Go to Start Menu. Search for Settings and open it.
Click on Update and & Security.0x80004005 Error Code Windows
From the left panel, click on Troubleshoot.
Select Windows Update. Then click on Run the troubleshooter.0x80004005 error windows update
The troubleshooter will now automatically find and fix any problem that stops your computer from downloading and installing Windows updates.

If running troubleshooter doesn’t help fix the problem, it may indicate that there are corrupted system files that causes the unspecified error 0x80004005. Try running SFC scan to automatically finds and repair system file in Windows 10.

To run SFC, go to Start Menu. Type CMD to search for command prompt. Right click the command prompt from the result, and click on Run as administrator. In the command prompt, type the following command.

/sfc scannow
system file check sfc scannow

It will now begin to scan and repair any corrupted system file found. It may take some time. After the scan is completed, try to run the Windows Update again.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure if the VirtualBox error code 0x80004005 is in any way related to the Microsoft error code 0x80004005 to which your answer seems to be related to - or is it? Currently, I cannot even start Windows let alone run Windows Update. I'm trying to run the VM on a Debian 9 machine

Comment: @david - This answer isn't relevant to your problem, the author of this answer, failed to identify the problem you actually have.

Comment: I know, but that's fine